# To distribute an iOS application in a no of devices

Tags: ipad, ios5, xcode4

I have developed an application using Objective C with Xcode 4.3.2 as front end and SUP 2.1.3 as middleware.I have a distribution profile with me and I have successfully run my application in an iPad.

Now If I want to run my application in one of my friends' iPad then is it necessary to get his iPad registered with the provisional certificate?And what all yhings I need to send along with my .ipa file?

Is it necessary for the tester to drag the provisioning certificate also to his iTunes?

I have got a very vague idea about all these things.And I am very much new to this.Please help me with a clear idea..Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an ad-hoc distribution profile for this purpose.

Follow the steps outlined [here](http://www.manyfriends.com/wiki/iphone/index.php/Create_an_ad-hoc_provisioning_profile) to do so. 
The provisioning profile will be embedded in the ipa, so no need to send anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer.I have asked a no of questions above.And now I have the answer with me.

I have a distribution profile with me.So the only thing I need to send or use is the .ipa file which we can create using Xcode.No need to send provisioning certificate along with that or no need to register UDIDs with certificates.